# cURL emulating by HTTPClient Apache

Tags: java, curl, apache-httpclient-4.x, crowdflower

I'm trying to upload data to CrowdFlower using their API, for which I'm writing JAVA wrapper. I'm using HttpClient Apache.

The cURL example CrowdFlower give is following: `curl -T 'sampledata.xlsx' -H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel' https://api.crowdflower.com/v1/jobs/upload.json?key={api_key}`

Here is my code:

```
public InputStream HTTPmethodPostUpload (String authKey, File file) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://api.crowdflower.com/v1/jobs/upload.json?key="+authKey);

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        ContentBody cbody = new FileBody( file,"application/vnd.ms-excel");
        mpEntity.addPart("sampledata.xlsx", cbody );
        httpPost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entityResponse = response.getEntity();
        return  entityResponse.getContent(); }
```

However it returns me an error with the following message:

> *{Un-Acceptable format, Content-Type must be one of those listed in "formats" but you sent "multipart/form-data; boundary=yTuwTm4hWmnasxIMB9dC-sxdELIGoNJVudjJdCz"","formats":["application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet","application/vnd.ms-excel","text/csv","text/plain"]}}*

I don't know Apache HttpClient well so I don't understand where is the problem in my code.

Comment: Probably useless now, but `curl -T` does NOT send any multipart type, only a simple entity. It also uses PUT not POST, although the server may have accepted both.

Answer (score 1):

where in the java did you set the header?

```
-H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'
```

try the below:

```
mpEntity.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly there is no such a method for MultipartEntity class.

Comment: The API should provide alternate access to HTTP HEADER.  That is what you need to set. The example that i posted was via the Entity object. Try a different route to the headers.